# help to listen what he is saying "of the order of n" or "on the order of n"?

Tags: word-meaning, pronunciation, listening

i am confused about the discussion on this hot [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109370/are-on-the-order-of-n-and-big-o-the-same-thing).

it seems that most people believe that the professor is saying "on the order of n".

the title of the question had been forced to that though, what i heard is "of the order of n" instead of "on the order of n".

plz help to listen what he is [saying](https://youtu.be/XNhOk80CeWo?t=1423) "of the order of n" or "on the order of n" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear him as saying **of** the order of n, which is supported by the subtitles.  However you will hear **on** or **in** as well.

OED gives several variants with the same meaning.

> **of the order of**:  (a) Mathematics (also **on**, **in the order of**, **of order**): of the same order of magnitude as;  (b) gen. (also **in the order of**): in the region of; somewhere about; to the extent of.

[image]

Comment: Agreed.  It's ***of** the order of N*, which is also the standard way to express this concept.